# Entity Framework Core 2 Migration issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am building app using ASP.NET Core 2 and DB part is  EF core 2.

i have model like this

```
public class User        
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }   
}
```

This is context file

```
public class EFCoreDbContext:DbContext
{
    public EFCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<EFCoreDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
}
```

and finally startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<EFCoreDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MooltiRoomDatabase")));
```

And connection string in appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MooltiRoomDatabase": "Server=DESKTOP-BCQ6IAU\\CHATDB,Database=MultiRoomChat;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

Through package manager console i was  runing `Add-Migration` the command completed successfully despite the fact that in DB it did not create corresponding table,after that i've read that i need to run `Update-Database` command for creating table and when i run this command, i got a error like this

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, 'Connection string is not valid.' You used "," instead of ";" before the Database.

So now you have:

```
"Server=DESKTOP-BCQ6IAU\\CHATDB,Database=MultiRoomChat;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

But, you should use this:

```
"Server=DESKTOP-BCQ6IAU\\CHATDB;Database=MultiRoomChat;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP Net Core there is also a development configuration that gets used. You should notice an icon next to app settings - the "drop down" icon. See if adding your connection string to the development config helps.

Also the way the app [settings get accessed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=basicconfiguration) has changed so make sure you are writing the correct code to receive the value.